# Inserted Images into Outlook 2007 Email Blurry

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, microsoft-outlook-2007

Does anyone have any idea as to why images that are inserted into Outlook emails are sometimes blurry?

This is making it very difficult to compose an HTML email in Outlook.

Comment: also see http://superuser.com/questions/211020/prevent-outlook-2010-insert-picture-resizing-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a similar quesiton here: [Why Outlook 2007 pasted images are larger than original?](https://superuser.com/questions/47294/why-outlook-2007-pasted-images-are-larger-than-original) that may hold the answer to your troubles in that it may be a zoom-level setting in Word that's affecting Outlook (as it uses Word as the editor by default).

If it's slightly zoomed in Word, then it will paste into Outlook at that zoom level, and possibly look/be slightly enlarged, so it appears blurry.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the default paste option has been changed from bitmap to Windows (Metafile).  Select Paste Special, and paste the image in as a bitmap and it acts as it did in previous versions with no blurryness.

Strictly speaking it's not standards compliant and not the best way to do it, but it never was.  All Microsoft have done is they've changed the default option in an attempt to reduce the size of emails being sent out.

I've looked for the setting to change the default paste option but can't find it. So I can only assume they've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite right. It has something to do with the format of the image in the clipboard or the program it came from. If use `print screen` to capture something and paste it into Word or Outlook there is no problem.

If I paste it into Paint Shop Pro first, then it’s all messed up. If I take that same Paint Shop Pro capture and paste it into MSPaint then copy and paste it into Word or Outlook it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2010...

I do this to email people a powerpoint slide in the body of an email.  But you could probably do it with an image also:

In the email, place your cursor where you want the slide or image. Then in the menus along the top of the email, choose 'Insert' menu.
Then select (in 'Illustrations'group) 'Screenshot'.
Then select a recent screen where the slide is huge.
That screen shot will be inserted.
Then right click on the screen shot, select the cropping tool, and crop everything out except the slide or image.

The slide or image will be super sharp.

Answer (score 1):

Actually in my case it only appears blurry while composing the email. When I send the email to myself, the email received is not blurry at all. Even the one in Sent Items shows the image as non-blurry.

[Using Outlook 2010, screenshot images pasted from the clipboard via Greenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image you upload is 96dpi.. That will fix it.

Comment: while too brief to be a good answer here, the 96pdi point can be vital. see http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/unsharpimages.htm for more.